# Deploying .bak file from SQL Server in Mac

Tags: sql-server, macos, deployment

Ok, I know this may sound stupid but, is there any way to deploy a database from a .bak file exported from SQL Server into any kind of Mac software? If there, which one?

If that is not possible, is there a way that I could deploy that database if I first deploy it into SQL Server and export it, maybe in a different way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you want to view the data? As a spreadsheet, or as a database perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

The bak file created by SQL Server is a database backup file, and you will only be able to restore it to a Microsoft SQL Server instance.

If you want to port a MSSQL database to some other RDBMS, your best bet is to use a tool for migrating the data directly from the running  MSSQL datbbase to another running RDBMS. Perhaps a third party tool, or you could build an [SSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services) package to do the migration.

You can create a MySQL database and try the [MySQL migration tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/migration-toolkit/en/).

But just given a .bak file, you will not be able simply to read the file; you will need to extract data from a running database instance.